# I'm trying to implement firebase for push notification in my ionic2 app

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I got following error while building the project for android platform**
**I don't know what's wrong in this.**

> Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin
>   (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of
>              date.
>       Error: ./node_modules/firebase/app/shared_promise.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in '/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/firebase/app'
>       resolve 'promise-polyfill' in '/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/firebase/app'
>         Parsed request is a module
>         using description file: /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/firebase/package.json
>   (relative path: ./app)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/firebase/package.json
>   (relative path: ./app)
>           resolve as module
>             looking for modules in /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules
>               using description file: /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/package.json (relative
>   path: ./node_modules)
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               after using description file: /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/package.json (relative
>   path: ./node_modules)
>                 using description file: /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/package.json (relative
>   path: ./node_modules/promise-polyfill)
>                   no extension
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill
>   doesn't exist
>                   .ts
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts
>   doesn't exist
>                   .js
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js
>   doesn't exist
>                   .json
>                     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                     /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json
>   doesn't exist
>                   as directory
>                     /Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill
>   doesn't exist
>       [/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill]
>       [/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.ts]
>       [/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.js]
>       [/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill.json]
>       [/Users/hardikjani/Desktop/Demo/ionic_firebase/node_modules/promise-polyfill]
>        @ ./node_modules/firebase/app/shared_promise.js 37:35-62
>        @ ./node_modules/firebase/app/firebase_app.js
>        @ ./node_modules/firebase/app.js
>        @ ./node_modules/firebase/auth.js
>        @ ./node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.js
>        @ ./node_modules/angularfire2/auth.js
>        @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
>        @ ./src/app/main.ts

I'm using:

ionic_firebase hardikjani$ ionic info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.4
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 6.0.0
npm        : 5.0.3
```